# Nodejs: is there a way to write a string to the user's terminal input?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I am trying to write a node script with behavior like this:

```
$ node derive-command.js
Deriving command...
Finished successfully, took 2.34 seconds...
$ curl https://abcdefghijk.com/api/e/12dce54
```

I am seeking an explanation of how to build a function `automaticallyType('curl ...')` that will cause the string `curl ...` to appear after `process.exit` has occurred, as if the user had typed this string.

I thought this might be impossible but then I found [node-copy-paste](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-paste). It's not exactly what I need but the `paste` command simulates user input in the same way I am hoping to do. Is there another way of doing this that doesn't require interacting with the user's clipboard?

Comment: So, are you just trying to inject data into the nodejs `process.stdin`?

Comment: maybe? I don't know if that would have the desired effect..

Comment: Please technically describe what you're trying to accomplish?  `console.log('Hello')` will write to the user's terminal.  So, beyond that, I don't think anyone here understands what you're trying to do.  We need more info in the question.  Perhaps if you show the `derive-command.js` code, we could see what it's trying to do.

Comment: `console.log('Hello')` will write to stdout, ie. the string "Hello" will be rendered to the terminal in a non-editable way. The key here is the last line of the example, `$ curl ...` where it seems like the user has just typed "curl ...". I am seeking an explanation of how to build a function `automaticallyType('curl ...')` that will cause `curl ...` to appear after `process.exit` has occurred, as if the user had typed this string. Does that make sense?

Comment: I would suggest you add that last sentence from your previous comment to your question itself (then I would have understood it immediately).  Anyway, I posted an answer below.

Comment: Okay, updated the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I deleted my answer.  Too much work to try to figure out what your question really means when it's missing so many relevant details and thus I wasted time with the batch file suggestion.